# Download URLs in JSON file starting with, including, and ending with different strings

Tags: regex, curl, grep, xargs

I have a terminal command I run to download all URLs included in a supplied JSON file:

```
egrep -o 'https:[^\"]*png' file-name.json | xargs -n 1 curl -O
```

This works as expected, but some of the URL's are in different "sub-folders", e.g.:

https://website.com/a-folder-name/display/image.png

or

https://website.com/another-folder-name/display-side/image.png

or

https://website.com/a-different-folder-name/thumb/image.png

I would like to adapt this command to only retrieve files from a specified folder name (so I can run the command again, changing the sub-folder name to only retrieve images in each folder), e.g.:

- File name starting with `http:`
- File name **including** `display-sides`
- File name ending with `png`

Below is a sample of my JSON data:

```
{
  "parent_groups": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Main name",
      "groups": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Sub Name",
          "components": [
            {
              "id": "id-number",
              "name": "Unit name",
              "image": "https://website.com/a-folder-name/display/image.png"
            },
            {
              "id": "another-id-number",
              "name": "Another Unit name",
              "image": "https://website.com/another-folder-name/display/another-image.png"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "display": {
    "side": {
      "components": [
        {
          "id": "side-id",
          "filename": "https://website.com/another-folder-name/display-side/image.png"
        },
        {
          "id": "another-side-id",
          "filename": "https://website.com/some-folder-name/display-side/another-image.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    "main": [
      {
        "position": 0,
        "conditions": [
          {
            "ids": [
              "thumb-id9"
            ],
            "filename": "https://website.com/irrelevant-folder-name/thumb/image.png"
          },
          {
            "ids": [
              "another-thumb-id"
            ],
            "filename": "https://website.com/this-is-a-folder-name/thumb/another-image.png"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is heavily cut-down from the files I work with but hopefully serves as a relevant example.

Comment: post a testable fragment of your `file-name.json` file

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've posted a cut-down example that should help.

Comment: you wrote *starting with `http:`* - but all your urls start with `https:`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've updated the original command to show `https` (typo)

Comment: also, should it consider only `"image"` keys or `"filename"` keys too?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Ideally it would be agnostic to the key names and just search for any strings matching the pattern 'starting with' - 'including somewhere in the middle' - 'ending with' (for future benefits if my files change), **but** currently images only appear against those two keys - so it would be sufficient to only search against those keys for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167084/discussion-between-chapmanio-and-romanperekhrest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
egrep -o 'https:[^"]*/display-sides/[^"]*png' file-name.json | xargs -n 1 curl -O
```

This could be made a bit more robust by taking the surrounding quotes into account as well:

```
egrep -o '"https:[^"]*/display-sides/[^"]*png"' file-name.json | tr -d '"' | xargs -n 1 curl -O
```

That will allow you to leave off the `png` file extension too, if you wish.

Comment: Amazing, thanks @Thomas - regex is not my strong-suit!

Comment: Regex is pretty easy to learn though, and _so_ worth it! Just a random link from Google that might help you: https://www.regexone.com/ Edit: note that that site uses Perl-like syntax. The regexp syntax accepted by `grep` and friends is a bit different from that (and more annoying to work with); for example, it doesn't have `\d` and `\s` but rather `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: ... but in some `grep` versions you can use `-P` to make it use Perl syntax instead.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is not the right tool for processing JSON data.

The right way with [**`jq`**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/) tool:

```
jq '.. | select(type =="string" and 
                test("^https://.+display-side.+\\.png$"))' file-name.json | xargs -n1 curl -O
```

This will find all urls independently of key names.
Also it can be extended to analyze only a certain keys.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman is right, and if what you are *really* looking for is the field in the JSON-structure:

```
jq -r '.display.side.components[].filename' foo.json |
  parallel curl -O
```